# tomcat 6 hangs after a few hours

Tags: windows, tomcat

We have an application on tomcat using SQL server on top on Windows server 2007 web (IIS disabled) it works smoothly for a few hours but then it suddenly stops answering requests.
Log aren't too informative. We've seen an NullPointer exception on a certain JSP, but the syetem only hanged 30 hours after that.
We see manly exceptions on Tomcat lo4j log...but nothing appears related.
THe application itself it partly black box

Answer (score 4):

Aside from application specific stuff (what resources is the application waiting on? is it holding references to them?) and turning up the logging level, try:

run tomcat with flags to output GC activity:

```
java -verbose:gc
```

[Here's](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html) a good reference on gc tuning, but to check for a hang you probably just want to see if it runs into a memory error.

You can also use jstack to check the status of your threads, see what's hanging:

```
jstack PID
```